# Create a circular image?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK to develop mobile apps. I'm trying to create a ball (in Photoshop CS6) and when I save it as a .png, it registers the corners of the rectangular file, how can I get it so it's just the image and not the transparent corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw an image in corona it's treated as a rectangle.

If you want to use the element in physics and you want it to be treated as a circle instead of a rectangle you can specify the **radius** when adding the body.

You can read about it [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/addBody.html), more exactly the circular body example.